# correlation coefficient for non normal distribution (weibull)

Tags: pearson-r, weibull-distribution, spearman-rho

I work with wind data. In order to estimate the strength of the correlation between two anenometers, in my department they usually calculate the pearson R.

As far as I know the pearson R should be used under 2 assumptions:
-Linear relationship between the variables (yes)
-The data follows a normal distribution (no, as wind data has a weibull distribution)

Should we use then a non parametric coefficient like spearman to calculate the correlation?

Answer (score 2):

Pearson correlation does not assume that the data are normally distributed but the Pearson and Spearman correlations ask different questions.  Pearson lets outliers have a lot of influence, Spearman does not.  Which you want is up to you.

Exact results will depend on the shape parameter, but Weibull has long tails, so it has outliers.